# Download PDF file in R

Tags: r

I am trying to download a pdf file from this website: https://antigo.aneel.gov.br/web/guest/central-de-informacoes-economico-financeiras?p_auth=BT53Dees&p_p_id=ciefseuser_WAR_ciefseportlet&p_p_lifecycle=1&p_p_state=normal&p_p_mode=view&p_p_col_id=column-2&p_p_col_count=1&_ciefseuser_WAR_ciefseportlet_arquivo=APLPAC0383_D_Ampla_DC_2021_A.pdf&_ciefseuser_WAR_ciefseportlet_javax.portlet.action=downloadFTP

However, when I try to do that with the function download.file(), the file is very small (less than 100 kb)

```
download.file("https://antigo.aneel.gov.br/web/guest/central-de-informacoes-economico-financeiras?p_auth=BT53Dees&p_p_id=ciefseuser_WAR_ciefseportlet&p_p_lifecycle=1&p_p_state=normal&p_p_mode=view&p_p_col_id=column-2&p_p_col_count=1&_ciefseuser_WAR_ciefseportlet_arquivo=APLPAC0371_D_Celpa_DC_2021_A.pdf&_ciefseuser_WAR_ciefseportlet_javax.portlet.action=downloadFTP",
  "file.pdf", mode = "wb")
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I can't access this file in my web browser or in R. The server times out.

Comment: Just based on the link, it looks like the link is not to a pdf file, but a javascript button that does an action. You probably need to emulate a browser for that link to work.

Comment: I also can't access the file in the web browser or in R.